# Having trouble making A record redirect because azure website won't resolve ip address to website

Tags: azure, dns, hosting

I've created an Azure website which is up and running ok

[daphine.azurewebsites.net](http://daphine.azurewebsites.net)

This has the default page.  When I ping that address I get the IP address but the ping fails and times out each try.

`65.52.128.33`

My problem is that it won't resolve the IP to the daphine address.

I've bought a domain and I've set up all the redirection with the `CNAME record` which works fine however the `A record` redirects to the IP which fails.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a litte more to it than simply pinging the CNAME and using that IP if you want A-records to work correctly.

First you'll need to set up domain validation. This means you'll need to have a custom subdomain point to a verification domain, like this:

awverify.www.contoso.com > awverify.mysite.azurewebsites.net

After doing this you'll need to go back to the Portal, open your Web Site and go to the Configure tab where you'll be able to manage the domains. The manage domains dialog will show you the IP you can use for the A-record.

Follow this tutorial for more information: [Configuring a custom domain name for a Windows Azure web site](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/)

Comment: Is the awverify... CNAME record necessary *only* for the verification step, and it can be deleted following verification, or does it need to persist?